# Open netrw view of directory with Ctrl-P

Tags: netrw, plugin-ctrlp

Is it possible to use [Ctrl-P](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) to search for directories in addition to searching for files? I want to be able to search for directories in my project in whatever mode (`CtrlP`, `CtrlPMRU`, or other) and when I select a directory from the options I want a netrw view of the directory to open in the window.

For example if my project structure is:

```
src
├── foo
│   └── foo.py
├── bar
│   └── bar.py
```

and I open Ctrl-P in `CtrlP` mode I want the options to be:

```
src/
src/foo/
src/foo/foo.py
src/bar/
src/bar/bar.py
```

and then if I selected `src/foo/`, I would want a netrw view of `src/foo/`, i.e. showing something like:

```
../
./
foo.py
```

Comment: @D.BenKnoble sorry question was not very clear, just rewrote to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to do what you are asking for because it means mixing to opposite concepts: CtrlP is a fuzzy finder and usually people use it to find files without having to worry about navigating in a netrw like view.

Maybe you could have a look at [`:h :CtrlPDir`](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim/blob/6e4fb3b45faf96a7fb500d2920cfeeab24aa39fb/doc/ctrlp.txt#L1091-L1101) which could help you searching files only in a specific directory.